# Book where a poor Creole teenager develops powers; his future self became evil and ended the world

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book when I was younger. I can’t remember much except the main character is a Creole teenage boy who is poor and lives with his mother. He loves his mother a lot, his name might be Nick?

He starts to develop powers and is then visited by someone in his head from the future possibly? By the end of the book the guy from the future turns out to be his future self that turned to the Dark side with his powers and ended the world.

He is trying to go back in time to his younger self and prevent this from happening. I think he even meets a demon friend?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Approximately what year was this?  What kind of powers did he have?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is a good start, but a number of these plot elements are common, so more details could be helpful. Can you remember any other details? What did the demon friend look like (big red devil or an ordinary human being?) Also, Creole like Louisiana, Phillipines, Cape Verde? Did the book take place in the United States?

Answer (score 5):

"Chronicles of Nick" by Sherrilyn Kenyon. It's linked to her Dark Hunter series, but set in a slightly different world. Here's the wiki link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Nick